# Can I open a URL as a "file" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to open an URL `http://localhost/myendpoint.json` as a file in VS Code so that I can compare the result with a static `.json` file on disc.

Is this possible?

Comment: For localhost, isn't that also a static file on your disc, or is .json mapped to some script type in htaccess?  If you mean a file on a remote server, you can always use F12 in Google Chrome (dev tools) to save it.

Comment: Are you writing an extension?

Comment: No, I'm not writing an extension but I have looked through the extensions and there is none that I can see which does this. "GetURL" always makes a new file and "Paste from URL" will paste into the current document not overwrite it. I guess what I want is a virtual "file" mirrored to a URL...